# Select rows not matching a specified value (multi entries)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table with images like

```
imageID  imageName
12223    my nice image #1 
12224    my nice image #2
12225    my nice image #3
```

a table with categories

```
categoryID  categoryName
110         animals 
111         cars 
112         food
```

and a table image_to_category with

```
imageID  categoryID
12223    110
12223    111
12224    110
12225    112
```

i now want to select all images which are **NOT** in category 110. Technically this is only possible in the where clause of a much more complex query. So my first intention was to use

`... WHERE imageID IN (SELECT imageID FROM _image_to_category WHERE categoryID NOT IN (110))`

but this only works if the image has 110 as the only category. If the image is in two different categories it wont obviously work.

Is it possible to group the select in the where clause?
Or any other ideas?

thx.

Comment: Uhm, why use a 3rd table and not a foreign key linking the first 2 tables together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use an anti-join pattern.

We can write a query that gets all images, with an outer join to find matching rows in `image_to_category` with categoryID of 110.  Then we can exclude all the rows that have a match ...

```
SELECT i.imageid
     , i.imagename
  FROM images i
    -- anti-join 
  LEFT
  JOIN image_to_category c 
    ON c.imageid    = i.imageid
   AND c.categoryid = 110 
 WHERE c.imageid IS NULL
    --
 ORDER BY ...
```

---

We can get an equivalent result with a NOT EXISTS correlated subquery

```
SELECT i.imageid
     , i.imagename
  FROM images i
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM image_to_category c
          WHERE c.imageid    = i.imageid
            AND c.categoryid = 110 
       ) 
 ORDER BY ...
```

These are just two patterns. There are other query patterns that will return equivalent result.